# Functions $f\colon \{1, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, \ldots, n\}$, $|f(i+1) - f(i)| \le 1$ for all $1 \le i \le n-1$.

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know whether there is a  formula for the number of functions
$f\colon \{1, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, \ldots, n\}$, $|f(i+1) - f(i)| \le 1$ for all $1\le i \le n-1$.

$\bf{Added:}$ I needed this number to estimate the [covering number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_number) of the set of $1$-Lipschitz  maps from $[0,1]$ to itself, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217475/show-that-f-0-1-rightarrow-0-1-ft-%E2%88%92-fs-leq-t-%E2%88%92-s-for/4217879#4217879).

Comment: Whats's the answer for the first few $n$?

Comment: You don't need the number exactly, just an upper bound. $n\times 3^{n-1}$ suffices. There are $n$ choices for $f(1)$, and for each subsequent $i\in \{2,\dots,n\}$, there are at most $3$ choices for whether $f(i)$ is equal to, one more than, or one less than $f(i-1)$.

Comment: @Mike Earnest:  Thank you for your input!  An upper bound is good enough too.  Do we have a lower bound of a similar type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the adjacency matrix of the path graph be $U^{-1}\Lambda U$, then we want the sum of all the entries of the matrix $U^{-1}(\Lambda+I)^{n-1}U$.

We know that

$\Lambda_{j,j} = 2\cos(\frac{j\pi}{n+1}), \quad j = 1,\dots, n,$

$ U_{ij} = \frac{\sqrt{2} \sin(ij\pi/(n+1))}{\sqrt{n+1}}, \quad 1 \leq i,j \leq n.$

Although it may be easier to just take the power of the adjacency matrix.

On the other hand the initial values are $1,4,17,68,259,950,3387$ which **do** give a value on OEIS: http://oeis.org/A081113 . It seems there is a formula using some stuff I am not familiar with :/

Comment: Not that there's all that much information on that sequence...a nasty looking recursion (which may be only conjectural?  I didn't read that closely).

Comment: I don't know what I got myself into but it doesn't seem very promising at first glance

Comment: Thank you for finding it in OEIS!